# Is an Intel i5 always better than an Intel Atom?

Tags: laptop, cpu, intel-atom

I am looking to buy a (Windows) laptop. I know a little bit about computers, but there is a dizzying array of different Intel cores available.

In my mind, an Intel Atom is [8-year-old technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Atom) - and I don't want a computer that's as slow as I remember my previous computers being.

I always assumed that `Pentium` < `Atom` < `i3` < `i5` < `i7`. Is this a good rule of thumb, or do I need to take care when purchasing by comparing the numbers on [Intel Ark](https://ark.intel.com/)? Is there a good resource which explains and compares these?

---

<sup>I've tried hard to not let this question turn into a hardware recommendation or help with shopping (I know that's off topic). If it's not a great question I'm happy for it to be closed. If I can improve this question, please offer suggestions</sup>

Comment: There's no simple answer as the technology changes all the time and each CPU family (including Atom) is reinvented with new generations. It's better to use a website like NotebookCheck (https://www.notebookcheck.net/Benchmarks-Tech.123.0.html) to get an idea of how the hardware in one model compares to another.

Answer (score -1):

You can easily compare the performance of a laptop checking the GHZ of the processor combined with the amount of RAM.

For example even if you have a lot of RAM if you have a processor that has less than 2.0 GHZ (for example) you are going to be able to run without any problem programs like Office and music and video players.

If you want to use that laptop for developing at a low level you maybe want to check for a laptop with a higher processor GHZ and at least 4Gb of RAM.

In my own experience an i5 with 3.0 GHZ AND 4Gb of RAM runs pretty well but when I need to compile the QT creator statically it takes about 2 to 3 hours to get it.

In other laptop with 12 Gb of RAM but only a 2.1GHZ processor the same process takes about 3 to 4 hours.

If you need to use programs like SolidWorks or AutoCad you are going to need good amount of RAM like 8 or 12 Gb.

At the end depends of the usage you are going to have on that laptop to get the best combination of hardware.

Comment: Is the GHz and core count all that matters?

Comment: @Tim No - there's also the support in instruction sets, HT support, chip architecture in general, size of caches, speed of FSB/QPI,... If it wasn't for that, a Galaxy S7's CPU would easily beat a modern middle-class computer's one. In the same generation, your original statement is basically true - to be sure, try some CPU benchmark sites such as James P's suggestion or [CPUBoss](http://cpuboss.com/). And please note: Think about your use-case (e.g. "I need the battery to last 8+h, I'm only using office suite" vs "Battery life means nothing, I want to play FPSall the time!").

Comment: @flolilolilo That was what I was expecting - there's too many factors! I'm getting a mid-range iMac but can't afford the MacBook as well, so I'm looking at a PC for note taking in lectures. Currently I like the Linx 12.5-Inch - it's quite low GHz but 4GB of RAM should be plenty for OneNote and Chrome at the same time.

Comment: @Tim with your scenario in mind, visit a site that specialises on notebooks and reviews/compares them (like [notebookcheck](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Purchase-Consultation.13212.0.html)) and see what they say about it. The CPU alone won't do anything: I've seen high-specced notebooks with (relatively) poor performance as well as mid-specced ones with excellent all-around performance.

Comment: No Tim the GHz and the core count is not the only that counts, my answer was intended to provide a first approach because in your explanation you didn't mention the desired usage for the laptop. For example, Chrome is knowed that consums a lot of resources of the system, floliloio is right, the cache and another specifications like chip architecture is needed but I must insist, it's depending of the usage. I work with embedded systems and depending of the purpose of the system is the specifications we need.